# Choosing infinitely many subrectangles

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, elementary-set-theory

Let $R_1,R_2,R_3,...$ be any infinite sequence of pairwise disjoint closed rectangles in the unit square $[0,1]^2$. Is it possible to pick a sequence of subrectangles $S_n=[a_n,b_n]\times [c_n,d_n]\subseteq R_n$ such that the the open intervals $(a_n,b_n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are pairwise disjoint, i.e. so the projections of $int(S_n)$ onto the x-axis don't intersect?

Note: As pointed out in the comments, this equivalent to the question: given any sequence $[x_n,y_n]$ of subintervals of $[0,1]$, is it always possible to find subintervals $(a_n,b_n)\subseteq [x_n,y_n]$ such that the collection $\{(a_n,b_n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is pairwise disjoint.

Comment: If $R_n = [x_n, y_n]\times[z_n,w_n]$, then $[x_n,y_n]$ can be any sequence of closed intervals, right? So an equivalent formulation is: For any sequence of closed intervals $[x_n,y_n]\subset[0,1]$, can we choose pairwise disjoint open subintervals $(a_n,b_n) \subset[x_n,y_n]$?

Comment: @Milten Right. That would be equivalent. My thinking was if that the answer is positive then you could do it twice and make sure the $S_n$ project to disjoint intervals in both directions. But this question is equivalent to a one-dimensional question.

Comment: I am interested to know if you have solved it for the most basic case, ie the case $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = 1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @NazimJ In that case any sequence of disjoint intervals will do, e.g. you can pick $(a_n,b_n)=\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)$. It gets trickier when the $[x_n,y_n]$ overlap in complicated ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Assume that your sequence of rectangles has the property that for every $\epsilon>0$ and for every rational $q\in[0,1]$ whose distance from $0,1$ is less than $\epsilon$ there exists a rectangle in your collection whose projection to the $x$ axis is contained in $(q-\epsilon,q+\epsilon)$ (it isn't hard to construct explicit examples).

Any interval $(a,b)$ (in particular, the interior of a projection of a subrectangle of $R_1$) contains a rational $q$, so in particular, it will contain the projection of any rectangle whose projection is contained in $(q-\epsilon,q+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon$ small enough so that this interval is contained in $(a,b)$.